# loading multiple child components simultaneously in angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular4-router

I want my home page to show a preselected option from the sidebar menu. How would I do that? like I want when someone lands on the home page, he should be shown home>sidebar>about

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent, children: [{
      path: 'sidebar', component: SidebarComponent, children: [
        { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
        { path: 'clients', component: ClientsComponent },
        { path: 'services', component: ServicesComponent },
        { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
        { path: 'datatable', component: DataComponent }
      ]
    }]
  }
```

Comment: You cant display more than 1 children of a path at the same time.

Comment: then how do you acheive such a result?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **empty paths** and **redirectTo** property to achieve what you want.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent, children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/sidebar', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
      path: 'sidebar', component: SidebarComponent, children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: '/about', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
        { path: 'clients', component: ClientsComponent },
        { path: 'services', component: ServicesComponent },
        { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
        { path: 'datatable', component: DataComponent }
      ]
    }]
  }
```

You can refer Angular docs for [redirecting routes](https://angular.io/guide/router#redirecting-routes) and [child route configuration](https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration).